# make column have unique names in R

Tags: r

I have this type of data frame:

```
manufacturer  P

honda        33         
honda        32         
honda        32         
honda        29         
honda        32         
honda        34         
honda        36         
honda        36         
honda        29
```

I want to make the column manufacturer  have unique names. For example, honda_1, honda_2. How to do that?

Comment: `make.unique(your_data$manufacturer)`

Comment: `df$ID <- paste(df$manufacturer, seq(nrow(df)), sep = "_")` (where `df` is the name of your data frame)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
data$manufacturer <- make.unique(data$manufacturer, sep="_")
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- df %>% mutate(manufacturer = paste(manufacturer, 1:n(), sep = "_"))
```

Comment: @GregorThomas can I ask -- what's up with paste0 I used paste in my snippet but without a 0 ?

Comment: That doesn't much matter - `paste0` is a version of paste with `sep = ""`, so it doesn't insert spaces. I mostly use `paste0` so it was just habit to type it. If you wanted to match OP more closely you should use `paste` with `sep = "_"`.

Comment: ooo that makes sense I've been wondering that about paste0 haha

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions are simpler, this `dplyr` solution will automatically account for different manufacturers if you have them **made up data like yours **

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(manufacturer = c(rep("Honda", 4), rep("Hyundai", 4)), 
                 P = sample(29:36, replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
   group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
   mutate(manufacturer = paste0(manufacturer, "_", row_number())) 

#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#> # Groups:   manufacturer [8]
#>   manufacturer     P
#>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 Honda_1         30
#> 2 Honda_2         32
#> 3 Honda_3         34
#> 4 Honda_4         31
#> 5 Hyundai_1       34
#> 6 Hyundai_2       35
#> 7 Hyundai_3       36
#> 8 Hyundai_4       29
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, manufacturer := paste(manufacturer, rowid(manufacturer), sep="_")]
```